# Is there any way to know if a python webbrowser page has been responded to?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I'm using python to display a web page with webbrowser like this:

url = "file://c/python27/debug.html"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

The user then enters some values on the page and clicks submit.  At that point I need my python script to do another function call.  How do I know the user has clicked submit on the page that I displayed?

If not, is there a better way to display the html page so I CAN know that it was responded to with a callback or something?

Comment: You can't tell via `webbrowser`, that just opens a new window/tab.

Comment: I don't think there's any elegant or easy way of doing what you want. That method just launches the browser - it's not hooked into it in any way afterwards.  You'll need to somehow have javascript on that page... since it's a local file, I figure you can just modify it to load whatever javascript you want. Alternatively, if the page won't be served locally, you might be able to install a browser plugin or something that injects the javascript code you want into the browser. Not sure how any javascript code would actually communicate anything back to your python script, though.